# Usage of Requesters and Writers in Windows System Restore Point

Tags: c++, windows, backup, restore

I want to have some app files included in my **windows restore point**. Otherwise, they are not restored and causes the app to crash. Those files don't have an extension that is monitored (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sr/monitored-file-extensions).

**I wrote a writer** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/vss/writers) for those files (and at some point a writer for just one file) using vsswriter and using expressWriter as well. I was expecting that the OS would call its requester which would add the files at the writer to the restore set..

Since it seems that it doesn't work, I am wondering if there is a need to **implement a requester** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/vss/requestors) by myself which would be run with accordance to the app.

Thanks.